# Save files to Azure fileshare in the sub directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-files, azure-runbook

Below is the runbook code I am using to save the file to azure fileshare. But unable to save in subdirectory.

```
#Set the context using the storage account name and key
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey 


$s = Get-AzureStorageShare "X1" –Context $context


$ErrorLogFileName = "Test.csv" 
$LogItem = New-Item -ItemType File -Name $ErrorLogFileName
      $_ | Out-File -FilePath $ErrorLogFileName -Append


Set-AzureStorageFileContent –Share $s –Source $ErrorLogFileName
```

Here I have a folder structure like **X1/X2**. But unable to get there and save the Test.csv. infact able to save it X1 folder on the Azure fileshare. Any idea ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `-Path` parameter for [Set-AzureStorageFileContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestoragefilecontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

For example, the file share is X1, and there is a folder X2 inside X1. Then you can use the command below:

```
Set-AzureStorageFileContent –Share "X1" –Source $ErrorLogFileName -Path "X2" -Context $context
```

By the way, the command you're using is old, please try to consider using the latest [az powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.8.0) command. For example, you can use `Set-AzStorageFileContent` instead of `Set-AzureStorageFileContent`(if you try to use the az module, then please replace all the old commands with the new ones).